# What's the conversion rate from dead civilians to zombies?

Tags: blight-of-the-immortals

When zombies are sitting on a city, killing the populace, how quickly are new zombies born?  And is this different between the different units, or the same for all zombie unit types?

I noticed that orc hordes convert civilians at a rate of 5 dead civilians to one zombie orc; is it the same for all species?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't played for a while, but I remember the rates being linked to the size of the relative armies. For example trolls and treant zombies would grow incredibly fast, as they come in stacks of 30 and 40, while spellcasters would only grow very slowly as a stack is 1-3.

The rate of zombie generation seemed fixed at 1 stack / time period, but the death rate of civilians seemed to depend on the size of the city, and how long it had been infected for.

This might have changed over the past 6 months though.